# AI for Tic-Tac-Toe not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse, artificial-intelligence

I have created a AI for Tic-Tac-Toe containing if and else if statements and simply checking for if the computer can make a winning move or stop the player from winning. However, the code below, although it works but when computer finds that the player is about to win, it will block the player and make an additional move alongside that but I don't want it to do that but instead only make 1 move. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, thanks.

```
// Checks for if the computer can making a winning move
        if(buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[2].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
        } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[6].setText("O");
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
        } 

        else if(buttons[2].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("O") && buttons[4].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[4].setText("O");
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[8].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[2].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[2].setText("O");
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[8].setText("O");
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[4].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[4].setText("O");
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[4].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("O") && buttons[2].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[2].setText("O");
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[6].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[4].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[4].setText("O");
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[6].setText("O");
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        // From here I start checking if computer can stop the player from winning
        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[2].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
        } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[6].setText("O");
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[8].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
        } 

        else if(buttons[2].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[6].getText().equals("X") && buttons[4].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[4].setText("O");
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[8].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[2].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[2].setText("O");
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals("X") && buttons[6].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[8].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[8].setText("O");
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[4].getText().equals("X") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[8].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[8].setText("O");
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[6].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[4].getText().equals("X") && buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[8].getText().equals("X") && buttons[2].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[2].setText("O");
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[6].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[4].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[4].setText("O");
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals("X") && buttons[8].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[6].setText("O");
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        }

        else if(buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);                
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
        }
// This else statement is run if no winning or blocking move is found
    else {
            if(count >= 9)
                checkWin();
            else
                RandomMove();
        }

        checkWin();
```

Thanks in advance and I hope I have explained my situation properly, if not please let me
know.

**Edited:** 
Basically, the computer is making two moves instead of one when it blocks the player from making the winning move.

Comment: A lot of this logic is messy. There is no way we are going to come up with an easy solution using this code.

Comment: do you mean in terms of formatting or the code itself? There are 24 different possibilities that computer can make a wining move and 24 possibilities that computer can stop the player from making the winning move, and my code checks for all these different possibilities

Comment: It looks like the problem is not in this code, but somewhere else. This code contains only if else statements so only one button can be set. But maybe you call this thing multiple times...

Comment: What's _after_ the code you show? A "normal" move? You realize it must be in an `else` block too, right?

Comment: after this, there is a else statement running a random move, if blocking or winning move by the computer is not found.

Comment: edited the post with the else statement.

Comment: Perhaps the AI has discovered that the only winning move is not to play?

Comment: @AndyG, I don't understand what you mean. The AI does find the winning move and works as expected but when it tries to block the player from winning it makes two moves instead of 1.

Comment: Someone else seems to have gotten the same assignment as you, see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44608/tic-tac-toe-computer-ai. Maybe implementing some of the things there will make it easier for you to notice the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple. You literally prevented the player from doing this. You need to make "steps" right now. Right  now your code checks all the time and inserts the opposing marker in the spot to prevent a win WHENEVER.

This works, for the AI for most of the time. Except you are probably not differentiating between player turns and AI turns. Make something that only allows the AI do block on its own turn. Every other turn.

maybe put the ai logic in a seperate method. Then call that method every other turn. You can do this with a counter or whatever you like. DID YOU MAKE PLAYER LOGIC? IE CAN THE USER ACTUALLY CONTROL THIS OR IS IT PLAYING AGAINST ITSELF?

METHODS BELOW.

```
    public void playerLogic(){
       //here post all the first stuff for winning moves

    }

    public void AIlogic(){
    // put all the mumbo-jumbo logic for the AI blocking moves

    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        int counter = 0; 
        boolean done = false;
      while(!done){
        if(counter % 2 == 0){
            playerLogic();
            counter++;
        }
        else{ 
            AIlogic();
            counter++;
            }  
//WRITE CODE TO CHANGE THE 'done' condition so no infinite loop 
    } 
    }
```

Comment: The first half of the code works fine -  computer making the winning move, I am having problems with the computer blocking player winning moves - this is when the computer makes two moves instead of 1.

Comment: Yes, the reason is because you are allowing the computer to block whenever. You need to take that control away from that block of code except on "every other turn"

Comment: but you know if and else if statements aren't there suppose to only run 1 block of statement if its true and ignore the rest?

Comment: The program doesn't know when its turn is. Right now, it just sees "Oh theres two player markers, and that silly human is 'bout to win, too bad I get to block it because my BLOCK move is accessible in the code and running all the time

Comment: I sort of understand what you mean but how I can fix this?

Comment: Assuming all of the logic is correct. I looked over it for a while. I would just make methods. Put all the AI stuff (bottom code) in the AI method. Then you can call the AI block to execute, once done it will return.

Comment: making method of 1 if statement and calling it several times?

Comment: or separating the winning and blocking moves into methods?

Comment: I will post in my answer section above. Seperating into a simple way to call methods.

Comment: Just out of interest, is there a better way of coding the AI instead of using if and else if statements. If so, can you let me know. Thanks

Comment: FOR THE AI.. HMmm well.. I looked over this and it is pretty awesome! I may use it for something else. (chess perhaps). http://pervasive2.morselli.unimo.it/~nicola/courses/IngegneriaDelSoftware/java/JavaGame_TicTacToe.html

Comment: @Seeker this one is pretty legit as well. http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~sbrandt/13H/java/TicTacToe.java